# Update cookie's maxage to make it expire with Struts 2

Tags: java, cookies, struts2, httpresponse

I'd like to update a cookie that have a `maxage` (1 year) to 0. I want to make it expire because I found that is the only why that I have to delete it.

I'm trying to do `response.addCookie(mycookie)` with a cookie that have the same name of the cookie that I want to update.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to `setMaxAge(-1)` and add to the response.

Comment: thanks! that's worked and spotted me that I've to use the same domain for the cookie... I was really missing something. Now it's working with maxage(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed two important parameters: domain and path

```
mycookie.setMaxAge(0);
mycookie.setDomain(".mydomain.com");
mycookie.setPath("/myPath");
response.addCookie(mycookie)
```